# Qual a diferença entre XmlDocument e XElement?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xmldocument

Gostaria de saber a diferença de XmlDocument e XElement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`XmlDocument`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) representa um documento XML inteiro. É possível usar esta classe para manipular arquivos XML.

[**`XElement`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx) é uma classe de `System.Xml.Linq`, ela é usada para representar um único elemento **dentro de um documento XML** no *LINQ to XML*.

É possível usá-la para manipular, obter o valor, remover, alterar os elementos filhos de um elemento em um documento XML.

---

Note que a classe `XmlDocument` é parte do *namespace* `System.Xml` enquanto a classe `XElement` faz parte do `System.Xml.Linq`. Em LINQ a classe usada para representar um documento XML é a [**`XDocument`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: e xmlElement é a mesma coisa que XElement ?

Comment: @StandAlone Eu errei a escrita. Tá mais claro agora?

Comment: Eu possuo um XmlDocument e preciso passar um XElement para um metodo, no caso como vc disse o xelement é um unico elemento de xmldocument certo? eu consigo pegar um xelement a partir de um xmldocument ou nao tem nada a ver ?

Comment: @StandAlone Todo `XmlDocument` tem uma propriedade chamada [**`DocumentElement`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.xml.xmldocument.documentelement(v=vs.110).aspx), esta propriedade é do tipo `XmlElement` e representa o elemento raiz do documento XML. De modo análogo, toda instância de `XDocument` tem uma propriedade chamada [**`Root`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.root(v=vs.110).aspx) do tipo `XElement` que tem a mesma finalidade. Perceba que `XmlDocument` e `XElement` **fazem parte de duas API's distintas**.